# How to remove the csep/non-numeric error while generating heat map in R

Tags: r, plot, heatmap

I have a data that looks like this:

```
                                                  Cluster_Combined Cluster_1 Cluster_2 Cluster_3 Cluster_4 Cluster_6 Cluster_10
G-protein coupled receptor signaling pathway (15)                2         6         0         4         3         1          0
GTP catabolic process (69)                                       1         0         0         0         2         0          0
activin receptor signaling pathway (17)                          0         2         0         0         0         0          0
acute inflammatory response (7)                                  2         1         0         0         1         0          0
acute-phase response (8)                                         5         2         1         0         2         0          0
aging (5)                                                        2         1         2         0         1         0          1
```

Which I want to create the heat map, based on the values above, where columns refer to the cluster name and row the ontology terms.

Now I have the code below

```
library(gplots);
dat <- read.table("http://dpaste.com/1505883/plain/",sep="\t",header=T);
hmcols <- rev(redgreen(2750));
heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat),scale="row",cols=hmcols,trace="none",dendrogram="none",keysize=1);
```

Although it does generate the plot, it gave me the following error:

```
Error in csep + 0.5 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Furthermore, I cannot see the red-green effect in the plot.

How can I remove the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "cols=" argument to `heatmap.2(...)`. Try `col=hmcols`.

```
heatmap.2(as.matrix(dat),scale="row",col=hmcols,trace="none",dendrogram="none",keysize=1)
```